# How to force the customer to choose "Yes" in an "Yes/No" attribute?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, magento2-enterprise

I have a customer attribute which ask the customer to agree our **Terms of Services** with attribute code `tos`. How can I reject a customer registration when `tos` is chose **No**? And, how can I display the error message like **You must agree with our TOS**?

**NOTE:** There are no Checkbox on Input Type at Customer Attribute. I'm using Enterprise Edition so I can create customer attributes without coding.

Comment: you can use a checkbox for that

Comment: There are no **Checkbox** on **Input Type** at **Customer Attribute**. I'm using Enterprise Edition so I can create customer attributes without coding.

Comment: In that case instead of yes/no type attribute create a custom select type attribute with only one option "Yes"

Comment: Wow! What a clever alternative! You can answer it first and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can create a custom select type attribute with only one option **Yes**.

Comment: Just remember to choose **Dropdown** on **Input Type**, and choose **Values Required** to **Yes**